# ASP.NET Web.Config File Specifying A DataSource ConnectionString

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to use an 'SQL Express' (or is it SQL Compact?) .MDF file as the datasource on a simple website using a Chart control.

Locally, it works great; but only if the 'AttachDbFilename' has the full path.  Am I messing something up, or does it really need to be full path?  If so - how do I accomplish this without using something like Server.MapPath()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<add name="LocalSqlServer"
     connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
```

By default, the |DataDirectory| variable will be expanded as follow:

- For applications placed in a directory on the user machine, this will be the app's (.exe) folder.
- For apps running under ClickOnce, this will be a special data folder created by ClickOnce
- For Web apps, this will be the App_Data folder

You can programmatically set DataDirectory by calling `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", newpath)`